# How does Magic Sky Control work in the new mercedes-benz?

Tags: voltage, automotive, how-does-it-work

I came across [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pxGrtV2Mbg) new technology implemented by Mercedes Benz that allowed windows to be tinted just at the pressing of a button. I figured out that some voltage applied at the actual window would move some particles that would do the job, but I was unsure how this system deeply worked and what exactly was going on. Even after googling around, answers like [this](http://news.mercedes-benz.co.uk/innovations/magic-sky-%E2%80%93-technology-explained.html) from the official Benz website, seemed to be rather vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This window is most likely a suspended particle device (SPD), which is a form of [smart glass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_glass). Essentially there is a liquid between two sheets of glass. This liquid is randomly oriented when no voltage is applied, which reduces the light transmission. When a voltage is applied the particles (rod shaped) align themselves in a uniform direction. By properly controlling the geometry of the electrodes the orientation becomes such that light is allowed to pass through. This operates in a similar fashion as an LCD.

Comment: Rod shaped particles? What are they? Or are they just organized in a multi rod-like pattern much like the polymers that make a polariod for instance?

Comment: They can be just about anything that induces a dipole in the presence of an electric field. I suspect that each vendor considers their particular compound a trade secret. Sorry that I can't think of any specific substances that demonstrate this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Go the website of the company that invented the process and has licensed it to Pilkington and Mercedes, among others. If you go to the Research Frontiers, Inc. ([smartglass.com](http://smartglass.com/)) website and choose FAQs there is a section which explains how the process works.